# Human interpretable Neural Networks?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, genetic-algorithms

Say I made Neural Network Trading Algorithm. How to understand what it does?

**Example**

How **human** would do the job. Human look at charts and thinks, and then develops an algorithm like "make portfolio of 50/50 of SP500/Cash, if it changes more than 40/60 rebalance and make it 50/50". Easy to understand what's going on.

How **Neural Network** do the job. Set up a black box model, fit it on historical data (like how they teach [Neural Network to play Super Mario](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv6UVOQ0F44)). You see it generates some profit. But you have no idea how it works, all you have is some unreadable matrices filled with numbers.

So, what are the ways to use Neural Networks (or maybe other things like Genetic Programming) so that it produce algorithm in human understandable form?

- Model should be flexible enough to express common algorithms (like if/else etc.) and temporal things like "wait 1 month and then check" etc.
- Human should be able to understand it, and rewrite as human written code.

Comment: I think what you are describing are essentially [decision tree models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning)

Comment: @bdeonovic thanks, do you know if anyone used it to solve a task like play a game? Like super mario or maybe strategy?

Comment: No. Is it theoretically possible? Probably. But just because a hammer can get a screw into the wall doesn't mean you should use it. Get a screwdriver.

Comment: You will run into the [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality). A lot of the power of neural network approaches comes from their projection of high dimensional data into lower dimensional space. This is essentially what makes them "hard to understand". You could use projections and embeddings in decision trees as well...but at that point you are essentially doing neural networks.